# Unexpected tIDENTIFIER in template path

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I'll preface this by saying that I know a little Ruby but not very well, so this may well be a common Ruby mistake (but I can't seem to find an answer!)

I have this Chef recipe (run using Vagrant):

```
package "php5-fpm" do
  action :install
end

template "/etc/php5-fpm/pool.d/site" do
  source "php-fpm.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 0644
  action :create
  only_if "dpkg --get-selections | grep php5-fpm"
end

service "php5-fpm" do
  action :restart
end
```

This fails with the following message:

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/.../cookbooks/site/recipes/php-fpm.rb
================================================================================

SyntaxError
-----------
compile error
/tmp/.../cookbooks/site/recipes/php-fpm.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected
tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
    template "/etc/php5-fpm/pool.d/site" d...
                                  ^
Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /tmp/.../cookbooks/dosos/recipes/php-fpm.rb:1:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
    /tmp/.../cookbooks/dosos/recipes/php-fpm.rb:

end  2:  :restart" do-selections | grep php5-fpm"
```

This doesn't make a lot of sense to me because the "relevant file content" appears to be munged from different parts of the file.

Is there something Ruby has about putting forward slashes in strings (and if so, why not error on the preceding 3 slashes, unless it's running right-to-left?)

Comment: I'd bet the error is a missing double-quote further up in the recipe.  Can you paste the whole thing?

Comment: @DaveS. This is actually the whole file - unless Chef concatenates files together?

Comment: Nope, files aren't concatenated.  Are you sure this file has been uploaded to the server?  The error mentions ':restart" do-selections' ... but that's not what you've got in the recipe.

Comment: Ah I missed off a bit at the end but I had that commented out (it's where the `:restart` comes from). It is on the server but I've just noticed it's getting pushed with Windows line-endings - I'll see if that's the issue.

Comment: That turned out to be it! Thanks for helping me get there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using Vagrant to provision my server using the Chef scripts. The Chef scripts were edited on Windows, which were available on the Linux VM via a shared folder.

The mistake was that my editor on Windows was not configured to use Unix line-endings, which confused Ruby. Stripping carriage returns (`^M`) allowed the script to run normally.